# Basic pentaho installation issue

Tags: pentaho

I just unzipped pdi-ee-client-5.0.1-dist and ran my job (which is called from a windows .bat file via command prompt). Getting Error: Could not find or load main class org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen

When I run a kettle job from spoon it can't load jdbc driver. Which jdbc driver I should put in and where ?

Next step- I am planning to install pdi-ee-server-5.0.1-dist to have repository
Am I doing right ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have java

If you are connecting to a databases (IE MySQL), you must download and locate the drivers (mysql-connector-java-5.1.2.jar or whatever database you are using) in /pentaho/design-tools/data-integration\lib

For the server its required to do some further configurations such as export some environment variables.

Comment: Please respond to my question Basic pentaho installation issue -extn , which i just added. Somehow I am not able to post a answer to this question as I am a new user  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the `PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME` environment variable. PDI ships with a bundled jre. Mine for instance is in C:\Program Files\pentaho\java. Set the environment variable to that and see if it runs.

The JDBC drivers in your version are under the lib subdirectory of your PDI install. If the HOME variable is set correctly it should be able to find them.

Note also that there are other variables you may have to set eventually like KETTLE_HOME, PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS, and PENTAHO_HOME.